# TCP header option with 12 bytes

Tags: session, tcp

I'm trying to understand the TCP session. I tested a connection using TCP and I realise that initial the header options were with 20 bytes, but after the first ACK the header options were with 12 bytes.

Why the change? Because there isn't options available?

Comment: Can you post the relevant test netork dump ? What ACK are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

Some TCP options are only sent with the SYN packet:

- Maximum segment size
- Window scale
- Select acknowledgement
- TCP Alternate Checksum request

Looking at one of my network traces, the TCP header was 4 bytes larger in the SYN packet because of the maximum segment size option.  You could use Wireshark to see which options are being sent in your traffic.

The Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) has more detail.